# Strange cable mount

Tags: brakes, rim-brake

This morning I was following another cyclist in the traffic.
He had a road bike with v-brakes. And the brake had a strange cable mount, and I can not realize what is this and what it is for.
Had no luck googling it (since I don't know what to google), so here's the image:
[image]
What is this red thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're called [Travel Agents](http://problemsolversbike.com/products/brakes/travel_agents_-_6416) and are used to change the cable pull of a brake lever so you can mix and match brake styles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link - there's lots of interesting stuff

Comment: [This](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/travel-agent-installation-and-adjustment) is a more detailed explanation on how they work.

Comment: It's pretty simple, one cable along the small wheel and one along the big wheel. Then it's simple lever action to explain the effect on the brake pull.